# Enclosing a python Path variable in quotes?

Tags: path, string

I need help fixing a Python script, but know ABSOLUTELY NOTHING about Python (though I am an experienced programmer so I get the jargon.)

I have this script that is trying to write output to a generated path, but when I run it, it gives me an error saying something about "E:\Program", and when I check, sure enough, it creates a folder named "Program" in the root of my E: drive. I'm CERTAIN it is trying to write to "E:\Program *Files*" but the space is terminating the command.

I did find where "path" is assigned:

```
path = tkm.path_archuncomp + bs.path + bs.name + '.ext'
```

How would I enclose that path in quotes that are assigned to the variable?

Comment: Your question is lacking key information.  Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Inserting the quotes character appears to be the same as languages like C. Simply use "slash" notion:

```
path = \" + some_variable + \"
```

Unfortunately for me, repairing the script is more complicated than that, and doing so only created errors, so I can't confirm that was done properly. :(